# Chrome's Development Tools on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is it possible to open Chrome's Development Tools in Android? Is it possible to do so with Java?

I tried going into the settings and such, but is it possible to access the console and create cookie for the browser?

Answer (score 9):

Directly on the device? I don't think so. If you have a computer running chrome, and a usb cord for your phone, then you can use Chrome's remote debugger to access a web console on your computer that can inspect pages open in chrome, and any in-app webviews that have debugging enabled.

Basically, you just enable the developer options and remote debugging on your phone, and go to `chrome://inspect` in your computer's browser.

To debug an app's webview you'll need to modify the app to enable debugging.

See [Google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) for more information and detailed instructions.

Answer (score -2):

You can override the console.log function to save the contents of the console to a local variable. Then output the contents in a div at the bottom of the page.

Alternatively, you could use a bookmarklet to toggle a div that shows the contents.

Comment: Please explain how to carry out your suggestion to the OP's effect.