# How to display JavaScript console on Chrome (or a different browser)?

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, javascript

I want to quickly try some JavaScript code on an Android phone.

I cannot find how to open the console or something similar on either Chrome or the default browser. `about:debug` doesn't do anything, and I don't want "remote debugging".

I can download another app if necessary (but I don't want to root my device).

Comment: Related for Chrome: [Chrome's Development Tools on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/87365/44325)

Comment: Hm. It's not possible even in other browsers I tried (firefox, opera).

Comment: `about:debug` has to be entered on the same page that you want to debug, in case you missed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android#7750683

Answer (score 0):

That feature seems to be unavailable for all major Android browsers.

You could try Opera Mini instead:

1. Reset the console output by opening a new tab with the address `debug:resetconsole`

   [image: Reset output]
2. Open a tab on the page on which you want to do the inspection:

   [image: example.com]
3. Run JavaScript code on the page by replacing the address in the address bar with the following address `javascript:var%20n%3Ddocument.firstChild%3Bwhile%28n%20%26%26%20n.nodeType%21%3DNode.ELEMENT_NODE%29%20n%3Dn.nextSibling%3Bconsole.log%28n.outerHTML%29%3B`
4. Retrieve the output by opening a new tab with the address `debug:console`

   [image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Kiwi Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser). It is the only one that has debug mode built in, plus extension support on mobile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to root the device (Alternatively, you can try the non-root solution [LSPatch](https://github.com/JingMatrix/LSPatch)) and install an Xposed Framework, then you can use my Xposed module [ChromeXt](https://github.com/JingMatrix/ChromeXt).
It supports showing the console with Eruda Console and with DevTools. See screenshots of both of them respectively:

[image: Eruda Console using ChromeXt]
[image: DevTools using ChromeXt]