# Is there any way to run android app under chrome in windows? or use chrome "dev tools" inside an android app?

Tags: chrome-for-android, windows, emulators

I use a platform that runs natively under any web browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.) and they also have an Android and iPhone app.

This platform is running a little bit crazy under Windows Chrome or Firefox due to network restrictions from where I work, but for some unknown reason, it runs fine inside the Android app.

I tried the app under the Bluestacks emulator and it ran fine, but I don´t want to have the emulator running and can't be on the phone all the time.

I wonder if it´s possible to run the Android app inside Chrome (in Windows 10) or if it's possible to run some sort of dev tools inside Android to try to understand what´s wrong with the native website and why it works fine inside the Android platform.

Any light in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The network restriction is probably in the form of a PAC file in Proxy Settings enabled for the browser that may block the site or it's js/css assets from whatever CDN the site is using, which might be what caused the link to not work.

Comment: Chrome has built-in developer tools for monitor and debug web applications. But that is a topic that belongs more to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have some questions that may be related/possible dupe: [Does ARC Welder still work? (running Android apps on Chrome)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205303/44325), [Chrome's Development Tools on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/87365/44325)

Answer (score 0):

For running Andorid app under Chrome, the answer is **no**.
Even on ChromeOS, the Chrome browser and the android system are separated.

For using `DevTools`, if USB debugging shows nothing from your PC side, then it is impossible.

You may try reverse ennigering your app. For example:

1. Capture the HTTPS requests and analyse headers
2. Decompile apk and analyse smali codes.